# How can I sign a pdf document with XML digital signature?

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature, xml-signature

I am preparing MessageDigest(SHA256) of a pdf document and sending it to a signing webservice. That service returns me a XMLSignature. Inorder to sign my pdf I am trying to attach this XML signature to it. How can I do it in java?

When I google, I am able to find many references relevant to XMLSignature being used to sign XML content however I cannot find how XMLSignature can be used to sign PDF document?

I know how to attach certificates to a pdf with private key but cannot figure out how the XML signature has to be used.

I am able arrive at XML signature like below.

```
InputStream certificateIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(decoder.decode({base64_encoded_certificate}));
        CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(certificateIS);
        PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();
        //getSignatureElement returns the <Signature> element of the XML returned from the web service
        Element signatureElement = getSignatureElement();
        if(null!=signatureElement) {
            DOMValidateContext context = new DOMValidateContext(pk, signatureElement);
            XMLSignatureFactory factory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
            XMLSignature signature = factory.unmarshalXMLSignature(context);

        }
```

How can I proceed after this?

Comment: You cannot alter the PDF document by adding the XML response you get from the webservice, because that would change the PDF document making the signature invalid. But you can save the PDF document and the XML signature together in a container of your choice. Then this container contains the original data (the PDF document) and the signature for that (the XML signature).

Comment: could you please provide a sample code of using container? Are you referring to similar to [ExternalSignatureContainer](http://javadox.com/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.4.3/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/security/ExternalBlankSignatureContainer.html) implemenation?

Comment: No, just a normal new class with two fields, one for the content of the PDF document, the other for the signature. Something like `class Container { private byte[] documentData; private byte[] xmlSignature }`.

Comment: But that doesn't sign my document. I want to sign the document with the Xml signature that I am getting from webservice. XMLSignature follows a template like <Signature><SignedInfo></SignedInfo><SignatureValue></SignatureValue><KeyInfo></KeyInfo><Object></Object></Signature>

Comment: PDF have a build-in system for digital signatures you can use. But then you have to check if the external signing webservice support such a PDF specific signing. Based on what you have wrote it looks like this webservice is just a generic way of singing data/hashes and return the signature data. Depending on your requirements of how you want to sign the PDF it might be possible that you can't use the webservice at all, but you have to add a detailed description of your use case in your question.

Comment: As you say you want to *attach* the signature to the pdf, I assume you neither want a detached nor an enveloping signature but instead an embedded / integrated pdf signature. For that (in an interoperable manner)  you need a signing service which provides a CMS signature or at least a naked signature of arbitrary data bytes. Can your service create that?